# INSERT into sql error - internal server error

Tags: mysql, express

I am trying to insert some data on my app. On my `db.js`:

```
usersDB.create = async (name, age, contact) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.query(
      "INSERT INTO users(name=?, age=?, contact=?) VALUES(?,?,?)",
      [name, age, contact],
      (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }

        return resolve(results);
      }
    );
  });
};
```

Then on my `router.js`:

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let results = await db.create(
      req.body.name,
      req.body.age,
      req.body.contact
    );
    res.send({ message: "Created users" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

This however, returns an `INTERNAL SERVER ERROR` on postman and returns the ff on my console:

```
sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '='Your Builder', age=25, contact=689566) VALUES(?,?,?)' at line 1"
```

Any idea what am I missing here? How do I fix it?

Comment: The error is right before the query fragment listed in the error message. In particular, the syntax is incorrect, inside the first set of parentheses there should be only the list of columns; the values stay in the second set of parentheses. Like this: `INSERT INTO users(name, age, contact) VALUES(?,?,?)`. Read about the [`INSERT` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) in the MySQL documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
"INSERT INTO users(name=?, age=?, contact=?) VALUES(?,?,?)"
```

Contains a SQL Syntax error. Change it like this:

```
"INSERT INTO users (name, age, contact) VALUES (?,?,?)"
```

You first list the fields, without assigning anything to the single field, then you list the values you want to insert.

Comment: While this answer is correct, a link to the MySQL documentation of the `INSERT` statement makes it really useful.